# Write JS script to import bookmarks from excel file with links

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

Can i import the web links from excel file (in single column) or text file to the chrome bookmarks's new folder with javascript?

If it is possible, where can i get that script?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way I found to import url / links list from excel or txt / text document to chrome is :

1. open firefox (no this is not a joke ^^)
2. highlight all the cells with URL inside in excel
3. click & hold on the selected cells and move to bookmark zone from firefox and release the click (firefox understand what he needs to do and makes bookmarks)
4. open chrome > three dots on top left > bookmarks > import bookmarks > import from firefox

Firefox devs made this better than chrome clap clap

Comment: The question was looking for a way to perform the steps with javascript. This is a description of manual user tasks.

Comment: yep, I know but since this post was top 3 in google research for that question/problem and that the 2 first were posts where you can't comment, I posted a resolution here to help people who are struggling.